# Ajax call finished before Java Thread finished executing task

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multithreading, servlets

This is what happening right now

1. Am using jquery Ajax to call Server side Servlet code
2. Servlet code using thread to read a property file from remote location and write it to Servlet response object.
3. The Ajax call finished while starting the thread .

I want the Ajax call to wait for the thread to finish its task. i tried using JQuery when method but its not get called(using jquery version 2+) .

```js
  $.when(loadProperty()).done(function(a1){
    alert('load proeprty finished  :'+a1);
});
```

```js
function loadProperty(){
   var webappName = $('#webapps').val();
   var proeprty_type = $( "#property_type option:selected" ).text();
   $("#property_table").empty();
   $.ajax({
          url: "UDEPropertyManager?mode=getProperty",
          dataType: "json",
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
          success: function(data) {
          
     }
    });
    
   }
```

Comment: are you set async: false for ajax call??

Comment: A. Your function doesn't return anything. B. You won't need `when` once you fix point A

Comment: why the Ajax call finishes while starts new thread on Servlet ?

Comment: I hope you have already tried this option,when making the ajax call:  async: false,

Answer (score 0):

Again, never run threads in servlets directly, in your case it's completely non sense.

The new thread means, the new work should be started asynchronously. It means when you run a nw thread, the servlet continue its work and response to the client, which could be done sooner than the new thread initialized.

You may not run a new thread for this case.

If the result/message is ready, so response it ASAP, and client would get it.

You may read more about the servlet context and threads please. One does not simply run threads that way in a servlet context